# Unable to find database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I'm currently following [Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_first_example.htm). The code manage to run successfully. I am also able to retrieve the data.

However, I could not find my database in SQL Server Management Studio.

This is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContextDB" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EFMyContextDB;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my `DbContext`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name = MyContextDB") { }
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you manually edit this connectionString? By default the IDE generated should contain additional information.

Comment: I manually added the connection string as per the tutorial. The only thing I change was the datasource. It was `Data Source =.;`, I changed it to `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;`

Comment: Which are you using: db/model/code first?

Comment: @LeiYang code first

Comment: So you can connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS` with windows account, but cannot find the database `EFMyContextDB`?

Comment: @Alex yes. my databases do not have `EFMyContextDB` but all the other database are there.

Comment: @active92 Try run this in cmd: `sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E`

Comment: @LeiYang I've got some errors. Too long to type it here. I've attached it in my question.

Comment: @active92 it means the sql service instance is not running.

Comment: @LeiYang the second time I run the same command, I got `1>` in the next line.

Comment: Then try to input `use [your database name]; go; select * from [your table]`

Comment: @LeiYang This is what I have now. `C:\Windows\System32>sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E`    
`1> EFMyContextDB; go; select * from Student`    
`2>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126564/discussion-between-lei-yang-and-active92).

Comment: See Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info why you should **avoid** the `AttachDbFileName=` approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `user instance=True;` the database will only exist under your currently logged in users context. Im not too sure what impact this has in SSMS but it may be that you need to be logged in as that user to SSMS also

More info here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: If you look further down in the tutorial, it is there. Instead of using just `MyContextDB`, I'm using `name = MyContextDB`.

Comment: @active92 Oh didnt see that can you update your question with the DbContext you are using?

Comment: @active92 any reason you are using `user instance=True;`

Comment: that was the problem. omg. thanks so much. i removed the `user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True; ` and it worked.

Comment: @active92 no problem, ill update my answer. I think that creates the database privately under a specific user account. Im not too sure how you then see it in SSMS, i would guess it shows if you are logged in as your local user? Perhaps not?